# How do I efficiently (approximate) retrieve the maximum occurrence in a sub-group

Tags: pyspark, group-by

dataframe contains two columns:

```py
data  = [
  ("A1","B"),
  ("A1","B"),
  ("A1","C"),
  ("A1","B"),
  ("A1","C"),
  ("A2","B")
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,["ColA","ColB"])
df.show()
```

| ColA | ColB |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | B |
| A1 | B |
| A1 | C |
| A1 | B |
| A1 | C |
| A2 | B |

Running a `groupBy` on `colA` and getting counts gives me: `df.groupBy("ColA").count().show()`

| ColA | count |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 5 |
| A2 | 1 |

Running a `groupBy` on `ColA`,`ColB` and printing top two values gives me:

| ColA | ColB | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B | 3 |
| A1 | C | 2 |

I am looking to retrieve the maximum occurrence within each "top"-level group:

| ColA | ColB | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B | 3 |
| A2 | B | 1 |

**Note**

1. The data contains 20400 Partitions and contains 950,449,154 entries with a total of 14 columns
2. An approximate `max` occurrence is good enough too. I just don't want the `first` or `last`

Answer (score 2):

Group by ColA and ColB, then use count agg function and sort in descending order and select first row for each group.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc

result = df.groupBy("ColA", "ColB").count().orderBy(desc("count"))
result = result.groupBy("ColA").agg({"count": "max", "ColB": "first"}).orderBy("ColA")
result = result.selectExpr("ColA", "first(ColB) as ColB", "max(count) as count")

result.show()

+----+----+-----+
|ColA|ColB|count|
+----+----+-----+
|  A1|   B|    3|
|  A2|   B|    1|
+----+----+-----+
```